# Overleaf back to v1

Tags: overleaf

I am using [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) to edit my LaTeX documents. The problem for me is, I accidentally moved one project to v2. Now I can't take it back and I think v2 is still very wanting. Any idea?

Comment: For now, you can download a .zip of your project (now in v2), and then re-upload the zip to v1 to create a new project.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not possible to revert a v2 project back to v1. [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com) has a warning about conversion to v2, which is still in beta, being non-reversible.

You will need to manually copy your LaTeX code into a new v1 project and re-upload any associated files. Alternatively, you can download your v2 ZIP and re-upload it to v1, as a new project.

Comment: @aslv95 I suggest that you up-vote and mark this answer as correct.

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) Just a note that Overleaf v1 is now retired, and it is no longer possible to create a new project in v1. In case you'd like to update your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Once you login, you will get a display with text like this (usually on left corner of screen in Overleaf version 2):

Welcome to the Overleaf v2 beta!

Find out more.
To tag or rename your v1 projects, please go back to Overleaf v1.

Go back to v1

[image]

Click on v1 link you will be back to version 1 with classic Overleaf homepage.

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) Just a note that Overleaf v1 is now retired, and it is no longer possible to return to the v1 project list. In case you'd like to update your answer.

Answer (score 2):

On a more recent note, there is a folder with the V1 projects and those can be moved to V2 if you want to open them (there is no other way at the moment). When Overleaf acquired Sharelatex there were some issues but I would say they have been mostly fixed and Overleaf V2 works fairly well.